# Are ATA and SCSI commands implemented differently from vendor to vendor?

Tags: sata

While researching the SATA and SAS interfaces, I began to wonder how certain ATA and SCSI commands/features are implemented from one vendor to another.  In other words, while the hardware interfaces are standard, is there any standard implementation used in the firmware? For example, would it be incorrect in assuming that Western Digital's implementation of native command queuing is completely different from Seagate's?

Comment: The firmware is a proprietary code, that is definitely different for different vendors, unless there is some "traitor" developer, who have switched the company and leaked the know-how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SATA protocol stack is a part of the T13.org's ATA stack. This stack is defined in several documents for architecture, commands and physical transfer (SATA and PATA).

For example the ATA8 command set defines mandatory and optional commands. You can can test the availability of features in the IDENTIFY DEVICE response. The ATA8 standard defines only command and data structures as an interfaces. So the internal implementation is vendor specific.

Regarding NCQ:
NCQ defines up to 32 slots for outstanding requests, but many consumer HDDs / SSDs support less (e.g. 4). This saves hardware resources - if implemented with separate buffers - or reduces queue management in software.

Server HDDs and SSDs are not limited.